# I put a new menu with css+html and the others SOCIAL ICON NOT WORK ( HAVE EFFECT OF ROTATION )

Tags: html, css

**I put a new menu with css+html and the others SOCIAL ICON NOT WORK ( HAVE EFFECT OF ROTATION ) please help me ...** As its title, first 2 social icon not work when I add this menu Please say me what  change to succeed TO WORK ALL icons ..The problem is the menu , I KNOW FOR SURE Because before he could edit it fixed over the two icons that do not work

***HTML :*** + **CSS Demo**

**LINK TO VIEW DEMO :** https://codepen .io/GARDFIELD3/pen/WRLpdZ
I render answer winner .. SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH AND Thank :)

Comment: unites/bind link for view thank and respect

Comment: What is the problem? I see that all the social icons do rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually your div with id `#content` is overlapping the icons and hence icon dont recieve hover as they are below `#content`.

quick fix .. give `#content` a smaller width *line 66 of css*

eg

```
#content {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; }
body {
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 18px;
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   
}
 

html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,150,0,0.5), rgba(205, 0, 255, 0.5)),
     url(http://i.imgur.com/ZR1Dkyk.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}




#header_holder {
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
    left: 0;
 background: #222;
 z-index: 100;
 }

#header {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 46px;
 position: relative;
 }

#max3semneblue {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 46px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #cc1e1e;
 }


#noscrollright
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:#fff; 
}


#content  {  width: 400px; /*change is here */
            margin: 0 auto;
   float: right;
   padding: 1.4px 0 30px;
   padding-right: 55px;
            }

.icon       {  
        margin: 0 14px;
        width:40px;
        border-radius:3px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;}

.icon:hover
      {    -webkit-transform: rotate(350deg);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;}
  


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul {
     width:555PX;
   BACKGROUND-COLOR: RED; 
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #c61515;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
 font-weight: bold; color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #dff2fa;
  background: #19799f;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  border-top: 2px solid #dff2fa;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dff2fa;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  background: #dff2fa;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <title>Max3Semne #home</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <!--[if IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="all" />  
 <![endif]-->
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>

 <body>
<div id='header_holder'>
<div id='header'>
  <div id='max3semneblue'></div><div id='pink'></div><div id='green'></div><div id='orange'></div><div id='blue2'></div><div id='purple2'>
    <h4 style="position: absolute;  left: 80%; top: 0%"><div id="content">
  <div id="content">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Max3Semne/"> 
   <img src="http://wp-time.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/facebook.png" class="icon" /></a>
        <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/max3semne?l=romanian">
   <img src="https://web2schools.juliarizza.com/web2schools/static/images/message-icon.png" class="icon" /></a>
          <a href="http://www.max3semne.ro/forum/index.php?app=members&module=messaging">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/User_Circle.png" class="icon" /></a>
        <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/max3semne?l=romanian">
   <img src="http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/35241878917010420/2DDCE514E0EDF58F6C0071C21EB641F16B4508CC/" class="icon" /></a> </h4>
 <h3 style="position: absolute;  left: 0%; top: 0%">
  <div id="content">
           <div id='cssmenu'>
           <ul>
             <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
             <li><a href='#'>FORUM</a></li>
             <li><a href='#'>SERVERE</a></li>
             <li><a href='#'>ASISTENTA</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div> </h3>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your magic :))problem resolved.. DO YOU THINK YOU CAN HELP ME  to climb up menu  to  maximum ? I see that it remains a very small space